# Exchange hybrid mail flow

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016, exchange-hybrid

I have successfully installed and configured exchange 2016 for a hybrid setup in my organization mail flow is up and running for all scenarios except from on-premises to o365.
Every other flow works fine. 
Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: A dearth of details. How can we possibly answer this question?

Comment: You could start by suggesting places to cross check and common pitfalls to avoid.

Comment: Cross check what? You've given us ZERO details.

Answer (score 1):

Your on-prem Exchange organization must have objects in it that match the mailboxes in Office 365/Exchange Online.

Normally these would be Mail User or Remote Mailbox objects. If there isn't a Mail User or Remote Mailbox object for each cloud mailbox, then on-prem Exchange won't be able to route mail to the cloud.

You can manually create remote mail users in your on-prem organization that match with the cloud mailbox by using the process I outline here:
[How to reconcile user with both on-premise and cloud mailboxes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/782279/how-to-reconcile-user-with-both-on-premise-and-cloud-mailboxes)

For new mailboxes, the best way to make sure everything works is to create the new mailbox on-prem and then migrate it to the cloud. When you let the mailbox migration wizard migrate it, it automatically creates the correct Remote Mailbox object in your on-prem organization.

Comment: Ok so if I get you correctly, if the user mailbox is only in cloud and the account is not synchronized with on premises, mail from on premises mailbox won't get delivered to the cloud user?

Comment: @adeloyedeji Windows Azure AD Sync is (99%) **one way only** from on-prem to cloud, so anything that was first created in Exchange Online/Office 365 will not be present at all on-prem. If you make a mailbox in the cloud, your on-prem org has no way of knowing it even exists, much less how to route to it. You either have to manually tell the on-prem org about the mailbox, or create the mailbox on-prem first and migrate it. So even if the account **is** synchronized, you still will have this problem.

Comment: Yes sync is one way and if I understand you correctly, users should have been created onpremise not on cloud right? But since users have been created on cloud first, how do I solve this?

Comment: I guess I have to create the users on the on-premises AD using the same smtp id for the smtp matching right?